# Use alternate ODBC DSN if primary ODBC DSN does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc, dsn

I have multiple users who connect to a SQL Server through Access using one of two ODBC System DSNs: REPORT and REPORTS. They are identical except for the name. I periodically update or create new Access-based tools, which are then deployed to a shared network drive. I currently have to maintain two versions of each tool--one that uses REPORT and another that uses REPORTS. I'm looking for a way to test and relink the tables:

- If REPORT exists, use it and relink tables.
- Else If REPORTS exist, use it and relink tables.
- Else return error message.

I have experience using DSN-less connections in VBA, and this may be a viable option if there isn't a way to test for ODBC connections that already exist. I would ideally have IT standardize on the DSN names, but the history is so deep that I can't easily identify who uses which DSN.

Comment: You need VBA for this, you can build two connection strings, test which one is available and then update all `.connect` property for all linked table. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+refresh+linked+table

Comment: *I have experience using DSN-less connections in VBA* -- then I would use that. I find this much more straightforward (especially in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

Below is some code that firstly returns the DSN that works (by trying to import a test table from each of the two listed DSNs), and then loops through all linked tables in the database to set the DSN correctly if needed:

```
Function fGetODBCName() As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "dbo_tblTest"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=REPORT;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=TEST", acTable, "tblUser", "dbo_tblTest"
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='dbo_tblTest'")) Then
        fGetODBCName = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblTest").Connect
    Else
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=REPORTS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=TEST", acTable, "tblUser", "dbo_tblTest"
        If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='dbo_tblTest'")) Then
            fGetODBCName = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblTest").Connect
        End If
    End If
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "dbo_tblTest"
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3146   '   DSN does not exist
            Resume Next
        Case 7874   '   dbo_tblTest does not exist so cannot delete it
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fGetODBCName", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    End Select
    Resume fExit
End Function

Sub sRelinkODBC()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strLocal As String
    Dim strSource As String
    strConnect = fGetODBCName
    If Len(strConnect) > 0 Then
        Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
        db.TableDefs.Refresh
        lngCount = db.TableDefs.Count - 1
        For lngLoop1 = lngCount To 0 Step -1
            If Len(db.TableDefs(lngLoop1).Connect) > 0 Then
                If db.TableDefs(lngLoop1).Connect <> strConnect Then '   only relink if needed
                    strLocal = db.TableDefs(lngLoop1).Name
                    strSource = db.TableDefs(lngLoop1).SourceTableName
                    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strLocal
                    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", strConnect, acTable, strSource, strLocal
                End If
            End If
        Next lngLoop1
        db.TableDefs.Refresh
    Else    '   not able to find a suitable DSN

    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sRelinkODBC", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Whilst this works, I would strongly recommend that you speak to you speak to your System Administrators and get them to roll out a single DSN to all users using Group Policy.

HTH